# Unity 5.0.1p1 with vuforia 4.0.105 and ios 8.3 crash

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am trying to build `Xcode 6.3` my unity app on my iPad which runs `iOS 8.3` . Unfortunately it crashes after the splashscreen. The only response or error I am getting is this one:

> Could not launch "appname": process launch failed: failed to get the task for process 896

The number `"896"` is never the same.

When I build it on my iPhone, which runs `iOS 8.0` it works fine.

Is it possible that this is a Vuforia issue or is it unity 5 ?

EDIT: I started with a scene that has no vuforia elements in it. Now my app starts. But when I open a scene with vuforia I get a black screen like the camera can't start or something. BUT, the tracking works, it seems like the framerate is very very low, like 1 frame a second.

Answer (score 0):

this thread is a little bit older, but maybe other people are searching for a fix to the black screen issue:

The black screen issue affects currently Unity 5.0 - 5.1 and Vuforia 4.x.
Currently Vuforia seems to have problems with the iOS Metal API (which is auto selected on x64 device), to fix this issue:

In Unity goto "Build settings -> iOS" and click "Player Settings".
Now the Player Settings Panel should be opened on the right side.
Select the Tab "Other Settings" and set the option "Graphics API" to "Open GL ES 2.0".

This fixes the black screen issue for me on Mac OS 10.10 + Unity 5.x.

Hope that helps someone ;)